Exoplayer is using container duration for playing mp4 files from the url. How to make it read video duration
I am using androidx media3 player. I need to play back to back mp4 assets downloaded from URL.
These mp4 assets have been processed through a transcoder and it seems that after processing container duration is a bit over than the actual video duration.
When few of these mp4 files are played back to back, for each file that is played - video stays on last frame for some extra duration before switching to the next media file.
I think the problem is that that the exoplayer is using container duration to calculate when to trigger onTracksChanged() and onMediaTransition(). So, even though the video has been played till end, but it stays on last frame for few ms.
I have create the instance of Exoplayer using:
exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
                .setMediaSourceFactory(new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory))
                .setLoadControl(loadControl)
                .setRenderersFactory(renderersFactory)
                .setUseLazyPreparation(false)
                .build();

It seems ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory() reads metadata from the container and thats why I am assuming it is reading duration from container.
Is it possible to make/force exoplayer use video duration instead of container duration?
